# How to stop Text View from increasing in width from one side in Android

Tags: android

I am new to android studio & have encountered an issue. I have a constraint layout which has an image view & a text view. I have attached the screenshot of the constraint layout.

[image]

The text view contains the current climate of a location. For eg , when the climate is "rainy" , it shows rainy in the center. The issue I am encountering it that If the climate is "scattered clouds" or " heavy showers" (Basically if the text's length is relatively bigger) , it's no longer centered. It feels like text view in increasing in width from the left side but I want it to increase from the right side with start letter of text to be in the center position always. How do I Implement it

[image]

My code for the constraint layout ->

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                   <ImageView
                       android:id="@+id/ivTemp"
                       android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
                       android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
                       android:src="@drawable/te"
                       android:contentDescription="@string/temperature"
                       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                       app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tvClimate"
                       app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias=".96"
                       android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_11sdp"
                       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>


                   <TextView
                       android:id="@+id/tvClimate"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                       android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                       android:fontFamily="@font/aldrich"
                       android:gravity="center"
                       android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_110sdp"
                       android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                       android:textSize="18sp"
                       tools:text="Scattered Clouds 20°C" />


               </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: you can use ellipsize and horizantal scrolling if you want the text view to be of constant size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want it to increase from the right side with start letter of text
> to be in the center position always

If I understood correctly, you want your view to look somewhat like this:

[image]

That can be achieved using vertical [guideline](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/Guideline) in middle of screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/vertical_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_lock_lock"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/vertical_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="my very very very very very very very very very very very very very long text"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/vertical_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an empty `<View>` in the centre and constrain the `<TextView>` to that `<View>`